# indexing not updating cataloginventory_stock_status

Tags: import, stock-status, magento2.4.4

After upgrading to 2.4.4 or after doing a second store on same installation (dont know), the field cataloginventory_stock_status.stock_status is not updating from 0 to 1 when I import new products/stocks.

I have 3 websites in table store_website:

- ID 0 : Admin
- ID 1 : Store 1
- ID 4 : Store 2

In table cataloginventory_stock its pointing at website_id 0.
If I change that to eg. 4 and index, the table cataloginventory_stock_status is whiped.
If I change back to 0 and index, everything is back. And now with stock_status=1 the right places?
But the problem when updating records persists (indexing)

Comment: You should update cataloginventory_stock_item table too, and set the qty = 0. Depending on your system settings the stock status is calculated based on the stock items qty. That's why rebuilding your index will change your status. After updating cataloginventory_stock_item and cataloginventory_stock_status you need to rebuild the index.

Comment: But where is that setting for stock_status.
When opening the products from the product grip and saving, the stock_status changes to the right value. But suddenly my indexer cant change it?

I just tested with change the quantaty to 0, reindexing and it changes the quantaty back. But didnt change the status?

Comment: update cataloginventory_stock_item table too, and set the qty = 0

Comment: After updating cataloginventory_stock_item and cataloginventory_stock_status you need to rebuild the index